# Why the focus changed after I setImageBitmap for imageview

Tags: android, imageview, fragment, lost-focus

Problem: After I setImageBitmap for ImageView, the focus reset to the widget on top-left corner, why?

Description:
I use FragmentActivity+Fragment for tab. In one of several fragments, I use Gallery + ImageView for image browsing.
When a thumbnail is selected, the original image shows in ImageView, 
if I touch the thumbnail, it works fine, but if I switch the focus by keyboard, it doesn’t,
When I switch the focus to the next thumbnail by keyboard, the original image blinks, 
and then the focus reset to the widget on top-left corner which cause the tab switch, 
and another fragment repleace the image browsing fragment.

If I just switch the focus in Gallery and not change the original image,
the reset will not be done.

```
// These two listener works for gesture and keyboard operation seperately
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new GalleryItemClickListener());
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new GalleryItemFocusListener());



// and then find out original image and show
currentBitmap = BitmapUtils.queryImageByThumbnailId(Home.this,
                        application.getThumbnailList().get(index));
currentImage.setImageBitmap(currentBitmap);
```

Comment: I think this action will cause the UI redraw, so I avoid it by......